# WCF Service sends a .txt or .xls but not a .gz (Zipped file)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, zip

I have a WCF service up and running which saves a file to my server. I have tested this by sending a `.txt` file and a `.xls` file. The size of the `.xls` file is 90kb.

Now I have a zipped file `.gz` that is only 70KB in size but when trying to complete this operation I get

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400)
>   Bad Request.

When I have tried to search for this Bad Request most results lead to the fact that a large file is being sent and that I need to change the settings in the config file.

This is not the reason in my case as the `.gz` file is smaller than the `.xls` file!

Does anyone have any idea why this type of file cannot be sent the same as a text or Excel file???

Edit: Code Added

Here is the method to call the service

```
        string name = "New Doc";
        string file = @"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/fileZipped.gz";           
        string ext = file.Split('.')[1]; 

        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        stream.Close();

        var uploadFileServiceClient = new UploadFileServiceClient(); 
        uploadFileServiceClient.UploadFile(name, bytes, ext);
```

And here is my service:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]    
public class UploadFileService : IUploadFileService
{
    public bool UploadFile(string name, byte[] bytes, string extension)
    {
        string importDir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UploadFileDir"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(importDir))
            return false;

        if (!Directory.Exists(importDir))
            return false;

        string outputFile = Path.Combine(importDir, Guid.NewGuid() + "." + extension);
        string filename = outputFile.Split('\\')[2]; 

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(bytes);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
           return true;
    }
}
```

Like I say it works for text or Excel files.

Comment: have you tried to use [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) to get more details of error? Also showing some code would be much easier to understand where problem is.

Comment: What is the format of the request argument? A byte array? An encoded string?

Comment: I have tried tracing and found that in the Request Header the Entity has a content length of 103144 and a content type but in the Response Header the content length is 0?

Answer (score 0):

IF there is no "filtering proxy" inbetween:

We had something similar and the solution turned out to setup the MIME type on client+server accordingly...